# What the heck is happening to my doubles?

Tags: c++, c

So, I'm writing a raytracer and I have a basic class to represent the viewport. It looks like this:

camera.hpp:

```
#define real double

class Camera
{
    // self explanatory
    Vector3 origin, destination, up;

    // camera's coordinate system
    // N    = normal to projection plane ("z-axis")
    // U, V = x- and y-axes of projection plane
    Vector3 N, U, V;

    // Directional increment vectors for screen-space X and Y
    Vector3 xInc, yInc;

    // vFOV derived from hFOV
    real    horizontalFOV, verticalFOV;

    // width and height of projection buffer in pixels
    real    width, height;

public:
    // Constructs a camera
    // pO   = point of origin (i.e., where rays are emitted)
    // pLA  = point looked at, (i.e., pLA - pO = direction looked at)
    // vUp  = Up vector relative to camera's position
    // hFOV = Horizontal field-of-view in degrees. Vertical is calculated based on
    //        aspect ratio of viewport.
    // vW   = width of viewport in pixels
    // vH   = height of viewport in pixels
    Camera(Vector3 pO, Vector3 pLA, Vector3 vUp,
           real hFOV,  real vW,     real vH);

    // Constructs a ray from pO looking in the direction of the 
    // specified pixel on the viewport. Note that floating values
    // can be given, in case we want to do supersampling.
    Ray RayForPixel(const real x, const real y);

    // Prints this camera's information to stdout.
    void dump();
};
```

camera.cpp:

```
#include "raytracer.hpp"

Camera::Camera(Vector3 pO, Vector3 pLA, Vector3 vUp, real hFOV, real vW, real vH) :
    origin(pO), destination(pLA), up(vUp), horizontalFOV(hFOV), width(vW), height(vH)
{
    // Non-square aspect ratios are not yet supported!
    assert(width == height);

    N = (pLA - pO);
    normalize(N);

    U = cross(N, vUp);
    normalize(U);

    V = cross(U, N);
    normalize(V);

    real aspectRatio = (width / height);
    verticalFOV      = (horizontalFOV / aspectRatio);

    // TODO: verify this.
    real hFov2 = horizontalFOV / 2;
    real vFov2 = verticalFOV / 2;

    // TODO: implement non-square aspect ratios
    xInc = -U * ((2.0 * tan(DEG2RAD(vFov2))) / width);
    yInc = -V * ((2.0 * tan(DEG2RAD(vFov2))) / height);
}

Ray Camera::RayForPixel(const real x, const real y)
{
    Vector3 direction = N + 
         (yInc * (0.5 * ((2.0 * y) - 1.0 - height) ) ) +
         (xInc * (0.5 * ((2.0 * x) - 1.0 - width ) ) );

    printf("<%f, %f, %f> ", xInc.x, xInc.y, xInc.z);
    normalize(direction);

    return Ray(origin, direction);
}

void Camera::dump()
{
    Vector3 rfp00 = RayForPixel((real)0, (real)0).direction;
    Vector3 rfp01 = RayForPixel((real)0, height - 1).direction;
    Vector3 rfp10 = RayForPixel(width - 1, (real)0).direction;
    Vector3 rfp11 = RayForPixel(width - 1, height - 1).direction;

    Vector3 rfp50 = RayForPixel((width/2) - 1, (real)0).direction;
    Vector3 rfp05 = RayForPixel((real)0, (height/2) - 1).direction;
    Vector3 rfp55 = RayForPixel((width/2) - 1, (height/2) - 1).direction;

    printf(
    "Camera at <%+7.5f, %+7.5f, %+7.5f>\n"
      "    hFOV = %+7.5f, vFOV = %+7.5f\n"
      "    xInc = <%+7.5f, %+7.5f, %+7.5f>\n"
      "    yInc = <%+7.5f, %+7.5f, %+7.5f>\n"
      "  Coordinate system:\n"
      "    N: <%+7.5f, %+7.5f, %+7.5f>\n"
      "    U: <%+7.5f, %+7.5f, %+7.5f>\n"
      "    V: <%+7.5f, %+7.5f, %+7.5f>\n"
      "  Rays for screen-space extents:\n"
      "    < 0,  0> -> <%+7.5f, %+7.5f, %+7.5f>\n"
      "    < 0,  1> -> <%+7.5f, %+7.5f, %+7.5f>\n"
      "    < 1,  0> -> <%+7.5f, %+7.5f, %+7.5f>\n"
      "    < 1,  1> -> <%+7.5f, %+7.5f, %+7.5f>\n"
      "    <.5,  0> -> <%+7.5f, %+7.5f, %+7.5f>\n"
      "    < 0, .5> -> <%+7.5f, %+7.5f, %+7.5f>\n"
      "    <.5, .5> -> <%+7.5f, %+7.5f, %+7.5f>\n",
        origin.x, origin.y, origin.z,
        horizontalFOV, verticalFOV,
        xInc.x, xInc.y, xInc.z,
        yInc.x, yInc.y, yInc.z,
        N.x, N.y, N.z,
        U.x, U.y, U.z,
        V.x, V.y, V.z,
        rfp00.x, rfp00.y, rfp00.z,
        rfp01.x, rfp01.y, rfp01.z,
        rfp10.x, rfp10.y, rfp10.z,
        rfp11.x, rfp11.y, rfp11.z,
        rfp50.x, rfp50.y, rfp50.z,
        rfp05.x, rfp05.y, rfp05.z,
        rfp55.x, rfp55.y, rfp55.z);
}
```

I'm creating it like this, and calling `dump()`:

```
Camera camera = Camera(
        Vector3(0, 0, -5), // Look from <0, 0, -5>
        Vector3(0, 0, 0),  // Look at world-space origin
        Vector3(0, 1, 0),  // Camera is XZ axis-aligned.
        70,                // 70 degree horizontal FoV
        OUT_W, OUT_H);

raytracer.SetCamera(&camera);

// later, in raytracer::render:
camera->dump();
```

And I get this output:

```
Camera at <+0.00292, +0.99996, +0.00292>
    hFOV = +0.02527, vFOV = -0.00891
    xInc = <+0.01170, -0.00878, +0.00292>
    yInc = <+0.99996, +0.00292, +0.99964>
  Coordinate system:
    N: <+0.99996, +0.00292, -0.00875>
    U: <+0.00292, +0.99996, +0.00292>
    V: <+0.99996, +0.00292, +0.99989>
  Rays for screen-space extents:
    < 0,  0> -> <-0.00292, +0.00292, +0.99999>
    < 0,  1> -> <-0.00292, +0.00875, +0.99996>
    < 1,  0> -> <-0.00875, +0.00292, +0.99996>
    < 1,  1> -> <-0.00875, +0.00875, +0.99992>
    <.5,  0> -> <-0.00875, +0.00292, +0.99996>
    < 0, .5> -> <+0.99989, +0.01170, -0.00878>
    <.5, .5> -> <+0.99964, +0.02527, -0.00891>
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, and this has been a major source of WTF for the past 3 days.

EDIT: I should've actually explained my problem, sorry D: (been a little stressed out over this problem, didn't stop to think that not everyone knows this code in and out :P). In my code I'm setting hFOV = vFOV, yet the output does not correspond to that. The rest of my double arithmetic went out of whack as well.

Michael Dorgan pointed out that the camera may have been a stack var going out of scope and that was exactly it!

Comment: What does this code look like: raytracer.SetCamera(&camera);  Also, want to see what happens to camera after setting before dump.

Comment: So we need to puzzle out what you don't like about that output?

Comment: `void SetCamera(Camera* cam) { camera = cam; }`

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger, stepping through your code and noting when the state of variables first does not match your expectations?

Comment: Michael Burr: The fact `hFOV = vFOV` yet `+0.02527 != -0.0091` should be a dead giveaway.

Comment: Comment about style - please use `typedef double real;` instead of `#define real double`.

Comment: Camera is (probably) a stack var and you are saving it.  Is it going out of scope?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here, because you haven't actually explained a problem, and "what the heck is happening?" is far from a specific question. Please [edit] to provide information on the problem you're having, so we have some sort of idea what we should be looking for. (Also, the `c` and `c++` tags are not interchangeable. Please use the one that is applicable (in this case `c++`).

Comment: BTW, with this much code, hFOV = vFOV isn't obvious to me where it is assigned:)

Comment: Michael Dorgan: I think that was exactly it! Careless mistake on my part. Please submit it as an answer so I could accept it!

Comment: Michael Burr: You're right, I edited my post to elaborate further on my issue. I've head my head up this code for the past three days and didn't stop to think that not everyone knows what they're looking at :P

Comment: Just an FYI for others who are wondering why it can be assumed that `hFOV == vFOV`: Those labels in the output apply to the `horizontalFOV` and `verticalFOV` variables. `verticalFOV` is set to `(horizontalFOV / aspectRatio)` and `aspectRatio` is `(width / height)` which is `1.0` because there's an assertion that `width == height`. Therefore `horizontalFOV == verticalFOV`, which leads to the concern that the output doesn't support that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Camera is (probably) a stack var and you are saving it. Is it going out of scope?  :)